# how to make a floating div on another div contents by moving aside

Tags: html, css

I have to float a div on another div.

```
----------------------------------------------
|     div   |   asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsd   |
|  floating |   asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsd   |
|___________|   asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsd   |
| asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsdfsafasfsd        |
| asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsdfsafasfsd        |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
-----------------------------------------------
```

floating div makes the content move or wrap other contents.  this is responsive design too.

coding

```
<tr>
    <td style="background: #AAAAAA" colspan="2">
        <div style="float:left;display:block;clear:both;background:#fff;padding:5px">

            <p>navigation</p>
            <p>asdfsadf</p>
            <p>asdfasfd</p>


        </div>
                        <p> section1</p><p> section1</p><p> section1</p><p> section1</p><p> section1</p><p> section1</p><p> section1</p><p> section1</p><p> section1</p><p> section1</p>

    </td>
</tr>
```

thanks.

Comment: What's the question? Floating an element will do what you illustrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you need ?
check the snippet if yes you have just to put the inner div with float:left;

```css
.big{
    background-color:#eee;
    width:100%;
}

.in{
    background-color:#00FF00;
    float:left;
   padding:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
<div class="in">
div  floating
</div>asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsd   
 asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsdfsafasfsd       
asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsdfsafasfsd  asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsd 
 asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsdfsafasfsd asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsd      asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsdfsafasfsd  asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsd   
 asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsdfsafasfsd       
asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsdfsafasfsd  asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsd 
 asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsdfsafasfsd    asdfsdfsafasdfsafsfsafasfsdfsafasfsd  
</div>
```